OAuth Backend as Frontend with client credentials flow question
I have a backend as frontend oauth server protecting my api's which works when using a browser, now i need to set everything up for client credentials flows, but I would like to use the systems built in with the bff.
So when a browser based app authenticates its issues a sessionId, which is then stored in as a cookie.
So is the best approach to option an access token for it to create a session_id for that client and then the the same bff system across all clients?
any advice would be appriciated.
